# memoryview and column-major / FORTRAN buffer

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-cffi

I have a buffer (I obtain it as bytes through `cffi`) for an column-major array.

Is there a way to obtain a memoryview for it with the correct attributes for Python's buffer protocol ? The method `cast` lets me assign a new shape but does not appear to let one specify whether the view is row or column-major.

For example:

```py
# Let b be my buffer of bytes for a column major array of integers
shape = (5, 2, 3)
mv = memoryview(b).cast('i', shape=shape)
# Expectedly not what I want as this is then assumed to be a
# C-style row-major array
mv.to_list()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is no easy way to change the strides/shape of a `memoryview` without diving into C. The easiest way is to use NumPy (I create the buffer here, you should skip that line):

```
shape = (5, 2, 3)
b = bytearray('a' * np.dtype('i').itemsize * np.prod(shape))
a = np.frombuffer(b, dtype='i').reshape(shape)
a.strides = a.strides[::-1]
m = memoryview(a)
print(m.strides)
```

Comment: Thanks. The numpy solution you are proposing seems to be the only one that would not require writing a C extension to set the buffer's attributes. I opened an issue in the Python bug tracker - https://bugs.python.org/issue34778